# Lan local ip address of Android phone is constantly changing?

Tags: malware

I believe I am a victim of malware on my phone.

I have already flashed a new ROM and reset my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone many times. Using a network logging app and a "network connections" app shows me the live connections coming from my phone.

My local wireless LAN is `192.168.x.x` but I see the IP address change to `10.0.8.1`and then reverting back to my local WLAN IP address.

I do not even route that subnet in my network so how am I getting that address? Using network ping apps, I can ping that `10.0.8,1` address from my phone. It's even happening to my other android phone (Gamsung Galaxy Note 3). The S3 is rooted and the Note is not.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! That must not necessarily mean something wrong: your device can have multiple IPs, e.g. one for WiFi, one for your mobile data, and one "local" (in case there's no network available). So a shaky network connection would exactly look as you describe: when the network connection drops, the device reverts to one of its alternative IPs.

Answer (score 1):

is there an open wifi access point or a network you've connected to previously nearby? 192 and 10 are both private IPv4 blocks, so it doesn't make sense that your connection is bouncing between wifi and mobile data connections. mobile data connections normally lease public IPs using IPv6. your situation sounds like the device is bouncing between 2 WLAN connections.

hop into Settings > Wifi > Advanced. make sure that "Avoid poor connections" is enabled. this might help the device ignore the weaker connection. back in the Wifi menu, you can also choose to forget the network that's causing the problem by tapping on the SSID and selecting "Forget."