# what's my IP address location.. 22.87.160.96

Tags: z4root

Need help to figure out why my IP address keeps changing and how I can stop people from hacking my phone

Comment: Are you supposed to have a static IP? Normally the IP address changes frequently if you haven't specifically requested or ordered a static IP from your carrier. Also, how is your phone hacked?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you seen [Lan local ip address of Android phone is constantly changing?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119406/16575)? Looks like that's the same issue you're describing.